# office open xml: id="whatever" vs type="#whatever"

Tags: xml, openxml, docx, phpword, libreoffice-writer

I have two *.docx files, one generated by [LibreOffice Writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice_Writer) and one generated by [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) 0.14.0.

In the PHPWord version I have this:

```
<v:shape type="#whatever">
```

In the LibreOffice version I have this:

```
<v:shape id="whatever">
```

Are these basically the same thing? Like In HTML you'd do `<div id="whatever">` and then you'd access it using `document.querySelector('#whatever')`. idk if you can similarly select individual elements with Office Open XML but if you can is `id="whatever"` pretty much the same thing as `type="#whatever"`?

Comment: "Open Office XML" - in this case you are talking about [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) instead, the format used primarily by MS Office. Because of that, you may get better help if you add an MS Word tag, even though strictly speaking your question is not about Word.

Comment: Or perhaps `docx` should be the tag. People such as me who are LibreOffice experts use primarily ODF format, which is significantly different, so you may want to use tags so that MS Office experts find this question.